# Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and email I got the was blank

Tags: php

I'm new in this PHP coding stuff.. Once I trigger the Submit button, I got the error of **Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** and the email I received it was blank.

[Website](http://www.blastmy.com/email-marketing-contact.html)

HTML Form:

```
        <label>Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="span12" name="company" id="company2" placeholder="">
```

PHP code

```
$mailTo = "$email_address";

$mailSubject = "$email_subject";

$mailBody = "The form values entered by the user are as follows: \n\n";

foreach($HTTP_POST_VARS as $key=>$value)
{

$mailBody .= "$key = $value\n";

}


$mailBody .= "\n\n";

if ($show_ip_address == "on")
{

$mailBody .= "THE IP ADDRESS OF THE FORM USER IS: $REMOTE_ADDR\n\n";

}


if ($show_refering_page == "on")
{

$mailBody .= "THE USER WAS SENT TO THIS SCRIPT FROM THE FOLLOWING FORM: $HTTP_REFERER\n\n";

}


if ($show_browser_type == "on")
{

$mailBody .= "THE USER USED THE FOLLOWING BROWSER TYPE: $HTTP_USER_AGENT\n\n";

}


if ($show_date_and_time == "on")
{

$mailBody .= "THE TIME AND DATE THE FORM WAS COMPLETED: " . date("h:i A l F dS, Y") . "\n\n";

}


$mailBody .= "\nThis message sent via www.BlastMY.com! \n VISIT US AT www.BlastMY.com \n";


$fromHeader = "From: $from_email_name\n";


if(mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailBody, $fromHeader)) 
{

print ("<B><br></b>");

}

echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV=\"REFRESH\" content=\"0; url=$redirect_to_page\">";

?>
```

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Care to format a bit ? Please .

Comment: Sorry about this.. Thanks for editing it.

Comment: Have you tried print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS) before foreach loop,

Answer (score 4):

Don't use deprecated syntax, it's really bad. Use:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
```

Comment: Sorry this was my first time, how to accept the answer? just vote up?

Comment: @JoonKit , its different that Vote up  . Click on Tick mark / check mark below Arrow button .

Answer (score 2):

simply try this one;

```
$HTTP_POST_VARS = $_POST
```

and then,

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Like this

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
```

Answer (score 0):

showing the error because `$HTTP_POST_VARS` has been depricated [refer from here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

need to replace `$HTTP_POST_VARS` with `$_POST`

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
{
 //code here 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else is mentioning, this variable $HTTP_POST_VARS has been deprecated since PHP 4.1.0 and has been replaced by $_POST

This is the official link:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

You can try any of the answers mentioned above and just replace

$HTTP_POST_VARS by $_POST